# Drag file from WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, drag

I find a lot of samples where describe how to drag a file from a WPF app. I just need to export .txt or .csv file from my app when the user try drag listbox item.

```
var filestream = File.Create(@"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test.txt");
var barray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Some text");
filestream.Write(barray, 0, barray.Length);
//filestream.Close();
DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filestream);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
//filestream.Close();
```

But if I release on Desktop there isn't any file copied. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason file drop is not working is that you are not providing a list of files paths which is the requirement for this clipboard format.  To fix this...

```
var filename = @"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test.txt"
var filenames = new string[] { filename };
var filestream = File.Create(filename);
var barray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Some text");
filestream.Write(barray, 0, barray.Length);
filestream.Close();

DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filenames);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: Application deadlock while dragging the file from my App to windows sticky notes.. it working everywhere only while mouse on windows sticky notes. It hangs and the full application is unresponsive..